# Why is SwiftUI Map modifying the state of its calling struct, if no frame is assigned?

Tags: swiftui, frame, undefined-behavior, swiftui-map

**Setup:**

My app uses a SwiftUI `Map`, essentially as

```
struct MapViewSWUI: View {
    @Binding private var show_map_modal: Bool
    @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion
//…
    init(show_map_modal: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._show_map_modal = show_map_modal
        self.region = // Some computed region
//…
    var body: some View {       
//…
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
            .frame(width: 400, height: 300) // Some frame for testing
    }
}
```

Using this code, I can show the map modally without problems.

**Problem:**

If I out comment the `.frame` view modifier, I get the runtime error

```
Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.
```

with the following stack frame:
[image]

**Question:**

Why is it in my case required to set a `frame` for the `Map`? [This tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-show-a-map-view) does it, but Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map) don't.
How to do it right?

**PS:**

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71954884/1987726) to a similar question and tried to catch the error with a runtime breakpoint, but it does not show anything interesting:
[image]

I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68365989/1987726) to another questions related to the same error, but it doesn't apply here.

**EDIT:**

**Workaround found, but not understood:**

My map is presented modally from another view. This view has a `state var` that controls the presentation:

```
@State private var show_map_modal = false
```

The body of the view consists of a `HStack` with some views, and a `fullScreenCover` view modifier is applied to the `HStack`:

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
    // …
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $show_map_modal) {
        MapViewSWUI(show_map_modal: $show_map_modal, itemToBeDisplayed: viewItem)
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: [.leading, .trailing])
        }
}
```

If the map is presented in this way, **no** run time error is raised.

However, if I include (as it was done up to now) `.top` or `.bottom` in the edge set, the run time error `Modifying state during view update` **is** raised.
I would be glad for any hint to the reason.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the error is not related to the frame at all, but to the update of the region once the sheet is presented.

As you can see in my code, I update the region 3 seconds after presenting the seet. Then, the error shows up.

Could the be happening in your code?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var show_map_modal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            show_map_modal.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Show me the map!")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $show_map_modal) {
            MapViewSWUI(show_map_modal: $show_map_modal)
        }
    }
}

struct MapViewSWUI: View {
    @Binding private var show_map_modal: Bool
    @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion

    init(show_map_modal: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._show_map_modal = show_map_modal
        self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude: 51.507222,
                longitude: -0.1275),
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5)
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Button("Done") {
                show_map_modal.toggle()
            }
            .padding(10)
            
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
        }
//        .frame(width: 400, height: 300) // Some frame for testing
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(
                    center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                        latitude: 31.507222,
                        longitude: -1.1275),
                    span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your test. Actually, it is very hard for me (say, impossible) to read your code or the logs in your video, even if it is zoomed in. My impression is that you assign a 1st region during init, and after it appeared, you assign a 2nd region after 3 sec, and this happens apparently without the error that I described. My question, however, was, why my simple code without `.frame` modifier produces an error, but with modifier it does not.

Comment: I'm sorry. I re recorded the GIF without the code so it could be seen better and added the code to the answer. I hope this time you can see how the error you described shows up in the log.

Comment: You are surely right that the region update causes the runtime error. This is also indicated by the stack trace that I showed in my question. Apparently, assigning a fixed frame prevents the region update. But shouldn't SwiftUI be responsible for the layout instead of me? I think this is a SwiftUI Map bug. And I still don't know how to set a reasonable frame as a workaround.